# how to call python script from javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a backend python script where it retrieves the data from the sqlalchemy engine. And I would like to show the data in a search box where you can scroll down the list of data and select it. I read some answers to the similar questions like mine, (use ajax to call python script). But I'm still not clear about this. Here is my python script.

```
# models.py

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import pandas as pd

aURL = URL(drivername='mysql', username='chlee021690',  database = 'recommender')
engine = create_engine(aURL, echo=True)

sql_command = 'SELECT product_id FROM bestbuy_data'

results = pd.read_sql(sql = sql_command, con = engine)
```

Can anybody tell me how to create javscript code to retrieve that results and render it in my form? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Step 1: make your script available as a web service. You can use [CGI](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html), or you can use one of the cool server frameworks that will run standalone or WSGI like CherryPy, web.py or Flask.

Step 2: make an AJAX call to the URL served by step 1, either manually (look for `XmlHttpRequest` examples), or easily using jQuery or another framework (`jQuery.ajax()`, `jQuery.get()`).

These are two separate tasks, both are well documented on the web. If you have a more specific question, I suggest you ask again, showing what you are stuck on.

There are also many examples for the complete package available ("python ajax example"), for example [this](http://runnable.com/UiPhLHanceFYAAAP/how-to-perform-ajax-in-flask-for-python).

Comment: does the URL have to be web address? Can't I use the path to the code instead? By the way, I am using Flask

Comment: Yes, it has to be a web address. If you use path to the code, you will get the code itself, not the results of execution.

Answer (score 0):

Your Python server needs to do 2 things:

1. Serve up the AJAX javascript file itself (via GET)
2. respond to calls from the web client (via POST).

Also it should be threaded to support multiple simultaneous connections.
Below is an example showing how to do all of the above with the built-in `BaseHTTPServer`.

JS (put in static/hello.html to serve via Python):

```
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"/></head><body>
Hello.

<script>

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/postman", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    value: 'value'
}));
xhr.onload = function() {
  console.log("HELLO")
  console.log(this.responseText);
  var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  console.log(data);
}

</script></body></html>
```

Python server (for testing):

```
import time, threading, socket, SocketServer, BaseHTTPServer
import os, traceback, sys, json


log_lock           = threading.Lock()
log_next_thread_id = 0

# Local log functiondef


def Log(module, msg):
    with log_lock:
        thread = threading.current_thread().__name__
        msg    = "%s %s: %s" % (module, thread, msg)
        sys.stderr.write(msg + '\n')

def Log_Traceback():
    t   = traceback.format_exc().strip('\n').split('\n')
    if ', in ' in t[-3]:
        t[-3] = t[-3].replace(', in','\n***\n***  In') + '(...):'
        t[-2] += '\n***'
    err = '\n***  '.join(t[-3:]).replace('"','').replace(' File ', '')
    err = err.replace(', line',':')
    Log("Traceback", '\n'.join(t[:-3]) + '\n\n\n***\n*** ' + err + '\n***\n\n')

    os._exit(4)

def Set_Thread_Label(s):
    global log_next_thread_id
    with log_lock:
        threading.current_thread().__name__ = "%d%s" \
            % (log_next_thread_id, s)
        log_next_thread_id += 1


class Handler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        Set_Thread_Label(self.path + "[get]")
        try:
            Log("HTTP", "PATH='%s'" % self.path)
            with open('static' + self.path) as f:
                data = f.read()
            Log("Static", "DATA='%s'" % data)
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(data)
        except:
            Log_Traceback()

    def do_POST(self):
        Set_Thread_Label(self.path + "[post]")
        try:
            length = int(self.headers.getheader('content-length'))
            req   = self.rfile.read(length)
            Log("HTTP", "PATH='%s'" % self.path)
            Log("URL", "request data = %s" % req)
            req = json.loads(req)
            response = {'req': req}
            response = json.dumps(response)
            Log("URL", "response data = %s" % response)
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "application/json")
            self.send_header("content-length", str(len(response)))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(response)
        except:
            Log_Traceback()


# Create ONE socket.
addr = ('', 8000)
sock = socket.socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(addr)
sock.listen(5)

# Launch 10 listener threads.
class Thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, i):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.i = i
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(addr, Handler, False)

        # Prevent the HTTP server from re-binding every handler.
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46210672/
        httpd.socket = sock
        httpd.server_bind = self.server_close = lambda self: None

        httpd.serve_forever()
[Thread(i) for i in range(10)]
time.sleep(9e9)
```

Console log (chrome):

```
HELLO
hello.html:14 {"req": {"value": "value"}}
hello.html:16 
{req: {…}}
req
:
{value: "value"}
__proto__
:
Object
```

Console log (firefox):

```
GET 
http://XXXXX:8000/hello.html [HTTP/1.0 200 OK 0ms]
POST 
XHR 
http://XXXXX:8000/postman [HTTP/1.0 200 OK 0ms]
HELLO hello.html:13:3
{"req": {"value": "value"}} hello.html:14:3
Object { req: Object }
```

Console log (Edge):

```
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
hello.html
HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype: "<!DOCTYPE html>".
hello.html (1,1)
Current window: XXXXX/hello.html
HELLO
hello.html (13,3)
{"req": {"value": "value"}}
hello.html (14,3)
[object Object]
hello.html (16,3)
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      req: {
         [functions]: ,
         __proto__: { },
         value: "value"
      }
   }
```

Python log:

```
HTTP 8/postman[post]: PATH='/postman'
URL 8/postman[post]: request data = {"value":"value"}
URL 8/postman[post]: response data = {"req": {"value": "value"}}
```

Also you can easily add SSL by wrapping the socket before passing it to BaseHTTPServer.